# How to Generate a Week Table and Split by Day and Hour

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, date, doctrine

First, to be clear; there is an example like this:

[image]

I can get courses with this query:

```
$qb
    ->select("c")
    ->from("ATLReservationBundle:Course", "c")
    ->where("WEEK(c.courseDate, 1) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE(), 1)")
    ->orderBy("c.courseDate", "ASC");
```

QueryResult:

```
{   "courses": [
    {
      "id": 110,
      "name": "Pilates",
      "quota": 8,
      "course_date": "2015-08-31T12:15:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stüdyo 2"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 135,
      "name": "Spinning",
      "quota": 8,
      "course_date": "2015-08-31T19:30:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stüdyo 2"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 154,
      "name": "Kick Box",
      "quota": 6,
      "course_date": "2015-08-31T20:00:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Stüdyo 1"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 133,
      "name": "Spinning",
      "quota": 8,
      "course_date": "2015-09-01T12:15:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stüdyo 2"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 113,
      "name": "Crunch 30 Min.",
      "quota": 8,
      "course_date": "2015-09-01T18:30:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stüdyo 2"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 112,
      "name": "Pilates",
      "quota": 8,
      "course_date": "2015-09-01T19:00:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stüdyo 2"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 150,
      "name": "Spinning",
      "quota": 8,
      "course_date": "2015-09-01T19:30:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stüdyo 2"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 136,
      "name": "TRX Group",
      "quota": 5,
      "course_date": "2015-09-01T20:00:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stüdyo 2"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 159,
      "name": "Pilates",
      "quota": 8,
      "course_date": "2015-09-02T10:00:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stüdyo 2"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 156,
      "name": "Stretching",
      "quota": 7,
      "course_date": "2015-09-02T18:30:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stüdyo 2"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 127,
      "name": "Zumba",
      "quota": 6,
      "course_date": "2015-09-02T19:00:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Stüdyo 1"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 148,
      "name": "Kick Box",
      "quota": 6,
      "course_date": "2015-09-02T20:00:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Stüdyo 1"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 138,
      "name": "Crunch 30 Min.",
      "quota": 8,
      "course_date": "2015-09-03T12:15:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Stüdyo 1"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 121,
      "name": "Pilates",
      "quota": 8,
      "course_date": "2015-09-03T19:00:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stüdyo 2"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 117,
      "name": "TRX",
      "quota": 8,
      "course_date": "2015-09-03T20:00:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stüdyo 2"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 131,
      "name": "Spinning",
      "quota": 8,
      "course_date": "2015-09-03T20:00:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stüdyo 2"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 142,
      "name": "Pilates",
      "quota": 8,
      "course_date": "2015-09-04T12:15:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stüdyo 2"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 147,
      "name": "LBT 30 min.",
      "quota": 8,
      "course_date": "2015-09-04T19:00:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Stüdyo 1"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 141,
      "name": "Crunch 30 Min.",
      "quota": 8,
      "course_date": "2015-09-04T19:30:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stüdyo 2"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 130,
      "name": "Crunch 30 Min.",
      "quota": 8,
      "course_date": "2015-09-05T14:00:00+0000",
      "studio": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Stüdyo 2"
      },
      "trainer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "-"
      }
    }   ] }
```

But i want to group this data like;

```
DAY - 31
    HOUR - 12:15 > Coursename
    HOUR - 19:30 > Coursename
DAY - 01
    HOUR - 10:00...
```

I don't know how to do this, anyone?

## UPDATE

New Query:

```
   $qb
        ->select("c, HOUR(c.courseDate) as hour, DAY(c.courseDate) as day")
        ->from("ATLReservationBundle:Course", "c")
        ->where("WEEK(c.courseDate, 1) = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE(), 1)")
        ->orderBy("c.courseDate", "ASC")
        ->groupBy("hour, day");
```

But; there is a problem with this query i could not group by `HOUR(c.courseDate), DAY(c.courseDate)` because i got this error:

> Error: Cannot group by undefined identification or result variable.

So, i defined hour and day as variable in select area.
I don't want to see day and hour as different variables.

QueryResult:

```
{
  "courses": [
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 110,
        "name": "Pilates",
        "quota": 8,
        "course_date": "2015-08-31T12:15:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Stüdyo 2"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "12",
      "day": "31"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 135,
        "name": "Spinning",
        "quota": 8,
        "course_date": "2015-08-31T19:30:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Stüdyo 2"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "19",
      "day": "31"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 154,
        "name": "Kick Box",
        "quota": 6,
        "course_date": "2015-08-31T20:00:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Stüdyo 1"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "20",
      "day": "31"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 133,
        "name": "Spinning",
        "quota": 8,
        "course_date": "2015-09-01T12:15:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Stüdyo 2"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "12",
      "day": "1"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 113,
        "name": "Crunch 30 Min.",
        "quota": 8,
        "course_date": "2015-09-01T18:30:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Stüdyo 2"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "18",
      "day": "1"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 112,
        "name": "Pilates",
        "quota": 8,
        "course_date": "2015-09-01T19:00:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Stüdyo 2"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "19",
      "day": "1"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 136,
        "name": "TRX Group",
        "quota": 5,
        "course_date": "2015-09-01T20:00:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Stüdyo 2"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "20",
      "day": "1"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 159,
        "name": "Pilates",
        "quota": 8,
        "course_date": "2015-09-02T10:00:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Stüdyo 2"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "10",
      "day": "2"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 156,
        "name": "Stretching",
        "quota": 7,
        "course_date": "2015-09-02T18:30:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Stüdyo 2"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "18",
      "day": "2"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 127,
        "name": "Zumba",
        "quota": 6,
        "course_date": "2015-09-02T19:00:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Stüdyo 1"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "19",
      "day": "2"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 148,
        "name": "Kick Box",
        "quota": 6,
        "course_date": "2015-09-02T20:00:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Stüdyo 1"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "20",
      "day": "2"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 138,
        "name": "Crunch 30 Min.",
        "quota": 8,
        "course_date": "2015-09-03T12:15:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Stüdyo 1"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "12",
      "day": "3"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 121,
        "name": "Pilates",
        "quota": 8,
        "course_date": "2015-09-03T19:00:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Stüdyo 2"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "19",
      "day": "3"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 117,
        "name": "TRX",
        "quota": 8,
        "course_date": "2015-09-03T20:00:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Stüdyo 2"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "20",
      "day": "3"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 142,
        "name": "Pilates",
        "quota": 8,
        "course_date": "2015-09-04T12:15:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Stüdyo 2"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "12",
      "day": "4"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 141,
        "name": "Crunch 30 Min.",
        "quota": 8,
        "course_date": "2015-09-04T19:30:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Stüdyo 2"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "19",
      "day": "4"
    },
    {
      "0": {
        "id": 130,
        "name": "Crunch 30 Min.",
        "quota": 8,
        "course_date": "2015-09-05T14:00:00+0000",
        "studio": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Stüdyo 2"
        },
        "trainer": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "-"
        }
      },
      "hour": "14",
      "day": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

I think i'm close now. But it must be like;

```
DAY
    HOUR
    HOUR
DAY
    HOUR
    HOUR
```

Comment: You can use Group By

Comment: I'v tried groupby hour and day. Will see after fix errors.

Comment: Can you provide me Table schema with some data

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: use `HOUR(c.courseDate)` in place of `hour` and same for `day`

Comment: No it's not gonna work. Only working defined as variables. Otherwise it throws error. >Error: Cannot group by undefined identification or result variable.

Comment: Then use it like as : SELECT * FROM(`YOUR FULL QUERY WITHOUT GROUP`) as t GROUP BY `YOUR COLUMNS`

Answer (score 0):

TO get your visual example table, use:

> WEEKDAY(date)
>
> Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 =
>   Sunday

```
select hour(date), -- group by hour
case when weekday(date)=0 then course_name else null end as Monday, -- 1 col for each weekday
.....
case when weekday(date)=6 then course_name else null end as Sunday

from table 
where -- select a monday to sunday calendar week unique by year 
date(date) - interval weekday(date)=date(curdate()) - interval weekday(curdate())
group by hour(date)
```

To get the other variant you mentioned:

```
select right(date, 2), -- day of month,
hour(date) --hour,
course_name
from table
group by 1,2
```